# Sorted hashmap iteration

Tags: java

I have such code:

```
HashMap<Long, TempPosition> positions = getTempPositions();
    for (SortedMap.Entry<Long, TempPosition> p: positions.entrySet()) {...}
```

The problem is the 'positions' is not sorted or non valid sorted. What the easiest way to iterate through the hashmap and save its current order?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `HashMap` by definition doesn't have an order. If you need to preserve or create some kind of order you need to use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Answer (score 4):

A HashMap doesn't have any order. If you want insertion order, use a LinkedHashMap. If you want keys sorted using their natural ordering or a custom comparator, use a TreeMap.

Answer (score 4):

HashMap doesn't have an order. You can't even guarentee that two HashMaps with the same keys will have the same order.

If you want an order using `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap` and the iterator will be in the order the collection provides.

---

Note: In some situations the keys will be sorted, so the keys are not even guarenteed to be random.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    map.put(i, ""+i);
System.out.println(map.keySet());
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implementation of [java.util.SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), like [java.util.TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SortedSet<String> sortedset= new TreeSet<String>(positions.keySet());

    Iterator<String> it = sortedset.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println (it.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the key can be sorted, this approach is the most simple:

```
HashMap<Long, TempPosition> positions = getTempPositions();
for (Map.Entry<Long, TempPosition> p: 
    new TreeMap<Long, TempPosition>( positions ).entrySet()) {...}
```

The trick is to wrap the map in a `TreeMap`. Note that this doesn't work (well) if the map is huge.

Comment: If it's just to iterate, I would bet that storing all the entries into a list and sorting the list would be faster.

Comment: True but if it was just to iterate, why is OP using a `Map.Entry` as loop variable?

Comment: To iterate over the entries (key + value). Your code does exactly the same thing (iterate over entries). And what I suggest is using a list of Map.Entry and sort it.

Comment: Hm. Didn't think of that. This would prevent to build the complex binary `TreeMap`. The downside is that you'd need to write a `Comparator` that works on `getKey()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a sample code using streams and classic foreach loop:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("c", "C");
map.put("a", "A");
map.put("b", "B");

for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : (Iterable<Map.Entry<String,String>>) map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())::iterator) {
    System.out.println("key:" + e.getKey() + ", val: " + e.getValue());
}
```